# Problems running Protractor on a Windows Jenkins Slave Node

Tags: jenkins, protractor, internet-explorer-11, gulp-protractor

I'm getting an issue while trying to run Protractor on IE11 on a Windows Jenkins Slave Node.

When I connect by remote desktop, I'm able to run Protractor with no issues. However, when I try to run Protractor from Jenkins I run into this issue:

```
[launcher] Error: UnknownError: JavaScript error (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 396 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.47.1', revision: '411b314', time: '2015-07-30 03:03:16'
System info: host: 'Win7', ip: '142.133.132.199', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreZoomSetting=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:12492/, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
Session ID: a43ccc90-f9f7-4465-98c3-dfb88751a5a9
    at new bot.Error (C:\Jenkins\workspace\sandbox\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108:18)
    at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (C:\Jenkins\workspace\sandbox\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:109:9)
    at C:\Jenkins\workspace\sandbox\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:379:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (C:\Jenkins\workspace\sandbox\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:130:15)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:9)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 100
```

This is weird, because I can run the same tests using any other browsers. Here are some things I tried:

- Made sure that Jenkins is using the same account as the one I'm logging in.
- Followed the steps on this blog: http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/
- Changed the protected settings, zoom level and registry key as per this website: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver
- Tried using the x86 version of the IEDriverServer

Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: Would like to point out that don't think it has anything to do with Jenkins or the tests in my case as I ran the example test provided on protractor repo to my internet explorer vm slave and it still got the above error.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I just set up a new VM for ie11 following the same guides you did, I'm still getting this Javascript error only on IE11... Tests run on chrome, firefox, and **IE9** (what?).  somehow still fail for ie11

Answer (score 2):

I found out that reading documentation is a good thing :) https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver

Read the configuring section

> For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target
>   computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance
>   of Internet Explorer it creates. For 32-bit Windows installations, the
>   key you must examine in the registry editor is
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. For 64-bit Windows
>   installations, the key is
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE. Please note that the
>   FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be
>   created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a
>   DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.

Worked for me...

Comment: Unfortunately, that is one of the first thing I tried to do. I even mentioned it in my original post.

Comment: Read that couple hours after I posted that answer, sorry about that... Curious if you ever figured this out?

Comment: Well I definitely missed this step in my configuration so thanks for that, but I still have the issue :(

Answer (score 1):

I too had problems with Protractor tests under Jenkins, all worked well when I run the test in console, but not in Jenkins.
Turned out, that IEDriverServer does not work, when Jenkins is running as a service (as is the default with jenkins window installer). For IE tests Jenkins **MUST NOT RUN AS A SERVICE**, instead Jenkins service must be closed and Jenkins started with

```
java -jar jenkins.war
```

(in jenkins directory)
(see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the versions of your node modules, specifically selenium, are the same on both the local machine and the remote machine.